# Qual a diferença entre top e margin-top no css?

Tags: css

Este é um assunto que sempre me confunde bastante. Qual a real diferença de ambos? Quando utilizar um e outro? Geralmente vou pela tentativa e erro, mas preciso entender como isso realmente funciona.

Comment: Ainda sobre o tema (ao menos funcionou para mim). Com a position: absolute, as coordenadas (top, left, right, bottom) funcionam bem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cada elemento no HTML sempre é uma caixa.

Essa caixa tem 4 valores de área:

1. A primeira, mais interna, é a do próprio elemento em si. No caso de uma imagem, é a própria imagem.
2. A segunda, é a chamada `padding`, em geral, ela é transparente e pouco usada. No caso de imagens, é algo como a parte interna da moldura.
3. A terceira, é a chamada `margin`. É a moldura em si do quadro da imagem.
4. E por ultimo, mas não menos importante, temos a `border`. É a parte mais externa da caixa.

Em `css`, você tem como manusear as propriedades de cada uma das partes da caixa com as propriedades:

1. `padding`;
2. `margin`;
3. `border`;

Agora, quando se trata de propriedades como `top`, `bottom`, `left` e `right`, você está alterando a posição do elemento, e assim a posição base da caixa do elemento.

Se você usa o Chrome, você pode clicar com o botão direito numa imagem, e clicar em `Inspecionar elemento`. No canto direito, você tem uma imagem da caixa do elemento que você está inspecionando.

Comment: Mas por que top, bottom, left e right nem sempre funcionam? Estão diretamente ligados ao position?

Comment: `Position` é uma outra forma de determinar a posição. 

Explicando:
 - Position determina o `tipo` de posicionamento de um elemento. Se o elemento é um bloco, se é um elemento inline, é nesse atributo que você determina isso.
 - `Top`, `bottom`, `left` e `right` são atributos ligados à margin.

Você pode ler mais sobre posicionamento [neste link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

Comment: Valeu! Entendi aqui:D

Answer (score -1):

O "top" posiciona o elemento em um coordenada, o margin-top usa como referencia os "irmãos" do objeto em questão, apenas dando um espaço.